# On Android, there is a way to know the list of the used apps?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if there is a way to find out the apps used on Android.

Exemplo : opened calendar, opened music player, etc;

Obs 1: It's not the list of openned apps. Would be more like a "log"

Obs 2: If there any mistake, sorry by my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there is a non-malicious/not-stalking use for this. You can check currently running apps as follows

```
  ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
  List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

The only options I can think of would be to periodically check and track what is currently running with a service (I'm not entirely sure that's possible) OR to intercept the actions of (that is, the intents sent to) the applications you were interested in, which would of course result in a chooser dialog for the user (as well it should, so that nobody can easily track someone surreptitiously)

Comment: Thinking through, my question seems a lot stalking. But that's not my intention. Do what Nick Cardoso said will be enough.

Thanks a lot.